# Several instances of the same object with different adjectives: singular or plural?

Tags: adjectives, singular-vs-plural

Should I say

> I've got a red, a blue and a yellow **balloons**.

or

> I've got a red, a blue and a yellow **balloon**.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)** If you have **one** balloon of each color, the sentence would be:

> I've got a red, a blue, and a yellow balloon.   (total number = 3)

**(2)** If you have **multiple** balloons of each color, the sentence would be:

> I've got red, blue, and yellow balloons.  (total number = unknown)

**(3)** If you want to specify the **individual number** of balloons of each color, it would be (for example):

> I've got a red balloon, two blue balloons, and three yellow balloons.(total number = 6)

Comment: It was option (1), actually.